# svg image expands outside its own limits

Tags: css, svg

I have a weird problem with a svg image. I've used it on many places in the code, but in ONE spot it expands outside its own limits.

[image: Normal acting image]

Normal acting image (light blue box shows the image borders)

[image]

Image expanding outside its own limits (light blue box shows the image borders)

The code for this particular image is as follows:

```
.logo img {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 130px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
```

Do you have experienced anything like this? Does anyone know why this is happening?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: does the image have a viewBox?

Comment: The svg is implemented as an <img>. The svg image itself has a view box but it is square like in the first screenshot above.

Comment: Then it will generally try to keep the viewBox aspect ratio. If you try to put it in a container with a different aspect ratio, it might overflow in one direction.

Comment: Alright, I see. The container has a dynamic width so I guess the viewbox stretches to fit it. Is there a way to make the svgs keep their aspect ratio inside a dynamic width div (without the need of changing the preserveAspectRatio settings for each and every svg)? I see the problem with the svgs not being inline, but I'd prefer keeping them as img if it's an option.. :S

Comment: They are keeping their aspect ratio. What do you want to happen if the aspect ratio of the image doesn't match the aspect ratio of the container.

Comment: Yes, the image itself is keeping the aspect ratio but the viewbox is not keeping its. I would like the viewbox to keep its aspect ratio so that the whole img tag is not taking up more space than it needs, eg not filling up the whole container div. Is that possible to do?